# What's the meaning of "eco" at the end of a sentence? Edit - it spells "ecco"

Tags: word-meaning

There is a huge number of children and grandchildren of Italian immigrants in my country and some of them are my friends.  More than once I heard a native Italian use the word "eco" at the end of a sentence and was curious about its meaning.
I then asked a friend of mine what his father meant when he said "eco" and the reply I got was "It doesn't mean anything".  Well, even if it doesn't mean anything, there must be a reason for using the word.   My question is: what exactly does "eco" mean when used at the end of a sentence?

I've tried to find the meaning of "eco" (not sure that's the way it is spelled) in Italian-English online [**dictionaries**](http://dictionary.babylon-software.com/italian/english/) but found nothing.

EDIT - I've never seen the written word so I'm not sure how to spell it (Eco, Echo, Ecco, Eko)  It's pronounced with an open "e" and a closed "o", with the stress on the first syllable.  I also heard it in the 1972 Italian movie "Il Caso Mattei" where the actor who plays Enrico Mattei uses it a few times at the end of sentences.

EDIT II - Now I know that the word is spelled "ecco".

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Could you give us an example frase? Maybe do you mean *ecco* rather than *eco*? (those are two different words, with different meanings)

Comment: @DenisNardin   Maybe.  I've never seen the written word.  It's pronounced with an open and strong "e" and a closed "o".

Comment: To me it seems more dialect than authentic Italian. Are your friends from Naples area?
It might be 'e cos'.

Comment: @nick: I also heard it in the 1972 Italian movie "Il Caso Mattei".  I'm not sure whether you spell it "eco", "ecco", "echo" or "eko"  The first syllable is the strong syllable.

Comment: The important distinction is the quality of the consonant, that is whether it is geminate or not. It would be really helpful if you could give an example sentence.

Comment: @DenisNardin   Unfortunately my Italian is very poor and I can't remember any sentence. However, it sounds like an appendage at the end.

Comment: @nick: Welcome to Italian.SE! Your post it's more a comment than an answer: for this reason it has been converted to a comment.

Comment: Note that the terms used by the 3rd or 4th generations of immigrants are those heard at home and probably used by their grandparents. They often are dialectal   terms that were used a century or more ago and which may be no longer commonly used now. Though regional dialects  are still well  present in Italy, their usage is less common than it used to be.

Comment: Not very relevant (unless the actor was doing some improvisation), but “the actor who plays Enrico Mattei” was the great Gian Maria Volonté.

Comment: I am native Italian speaker and live in Italy. I would say xxxxxx answer is right, definitely. Nowadays, "ecco" is used exactely the reported ways, and at the end of a sentence, as in the third example, is more like yours "that's it!". It's informal and mostly used in spoken language, but you can easily find it written in novels also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be *ecco*. Its usage as an interjection is informal and you can find it mainly in colloquial contexts, but it is shown in dictionaries:

***[Ecco](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/E/ecco.shtml):***

> - ***In funzione di segnale discorsivo, slegato da rapporti sintattici e collocabile in vario modo nella frase, serve:***
>
>   - a) in posizione libera, a riempire momenti di incertezza e a modificare l'impianto della frase: “mi è sembrato…, ecco, … ho saputo che lui…”;
>   - b) all'inizio di un discorso, per prendere la parola: “Secondo te, chi è stato dei due?” “Ecco. Per me il vero responsabile è Franco”; per esprimere disappunto: “Ecco! Ho dimenticato di nuovo le chiavi!”; per riprendere il tema principale del discorso: “Ecco, vi dicevo che in quegli anni …”;
>   - c) ***alla fine, per commentare e rafforzare le proprie affermazioni precedenti: “Sei un opportunista. Ecco!”*** 
>       • sec. XIII

Sabatini-Coletti

English translation:

Ecco:

> - ***Is used with a discursive function, detached from the syntactic context and placed in various ways in a sentence in the following contexts:***
>
>   - a) ***with no fixed position, to fill moments of uncertainty and to change the structure of the sentenve***: "I felt ..., *ecco*, ... I knew he ...";
>   - b) ***at the beginning of a speech, to start a sentence***: "Which of the two do you think it was?",  "*Ecco*. For me, the real culprit is Franco"; to express displeasure: "*Ecco*! I forgot the keys again!"; to resume the main theme of the speech: "*Ecco*, I said that in those years ..." ;
>   - c) **finally , to comment and to strengthen its previous statements: "You're an opportunist. *Ecco*!"** • 13th century

Comment: @DaG - would an American not understand XIII?

Comment: It's not the current usage to denote centuries with Roman numerals in English; since I was improving the format (italics etc.), I also changed this.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.  I still have some doubts, though.  Since it was so hard for me to make you folks understand what word I was talking about, I presume it must be very unusual in 21st century Italian. Am I right?  Second, sometimes it's very difficult to find the perfect translation for an interjection.  As "ecco" seems to be used in some completely different contexts and even as a filler, if you had to translate it into English would you translate it at all?

Comment: @Centaurus: Actually, it's a very common word, in colloquial Italian. Apparently, we were misled by the spelling “eco” which in itself means “echo” (and is also used, in an unrelated etymology, to refer to everything “ecological”).

Comment: @Centaurus I also would like to add that, although it is often used at the end of a sentence, this is far from the most common usage of the word, so it might not have been the first thing coming to mind

Comment: @Centaurus - here are a few translation examples as an interjection and a filler: http://www.wordreference.com/iten/ecco

Comment: Ecco!  Io sono soddisfatto. Grazie.

Answer (score 1):

I also think you mean "ecco", somehow it is like using "I mean" in english (it adds nothing to the meaning, but it "styles" your speech). "Ecco" should not be used in every sentence in written italian, only in the spoken one, being it a drastical choice.